# function fails but works at cli as oneliner

Tags: bash

This function I ripped off and hacked for my purposes:

```
function chkUrl () {
urlRegex="(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%=~_|]"

    url="$1" ; notSend "$LINENO" "url" "$url" "tn"
    #url="http://cloud0.storagedump.com/e7f8630b74678c157f37998a1f7e5151" #; notSend "$LINENO" "url" "$url" "tn"

    if [[ ! "$url" =~ "$urlRegex" ]] ; then 

            exit "$LINENO"

    fi
}
```

to validate that a URL entry appears good, *before* doing anything online, is erroring in a script and I can't see why. But entered at the cli as a oneliner, the commands run fine when fed the same URL that fails in the function.

I feel certain I am just making some obvious blunder that is not all too obvious to me atm if anyone can show me what it might be.

Comment: @Etan yeah ok, I would tend to agree, except as I elaborated, when run as a oneliner, inputting the same url that fails the check in the function, and yes, exits, the url checks out fne. Unless you are alluding to a different hint?

Comment: Indeed a different hint. You didn't clarify what "fails" meant. I took a guess at "fail" meaning to exit the script instead of just the function when the url was no good since `exit` will do that (it should also be exiting your shell session for that matter so I'm a bit confused by how this is working there in that case). Does that url in the snippet exhibit the odd behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an expression to be recognized, it should not be enclosed around double quotes:

```
if [[ ! "$url" =~ $urlRegex ]]; then
```

Also, `exit` would make the script exit. If you want to return a code from the function, use `return`

```
return "$LINENO"
```

Also note that in shell scripts, a "true" return value for a command is zero while "false" (has errors) is any nonzero. Try `true; echo $?` and `false; echo $?`

Comment: that works. Yeah actually it is not simply an `exit` but rather a tad dialogue that gets popped instead that I simply edited for an exit command to make things more streamlined. I should have also removed the `$LINENO` that I include in the dialogue to make it really clear. My bad. Muchos gratsias for the fix though.

Answer (score 1):

Native shell regex is a feature of Bash 4.x. Your oneliner probably works because you run it in your interactive shell, which is Bash 4.x.

If you put it in a shell script, with shebang `#!/bin/sh` you're left with POSIX sh functionality. No native regexes.

Try `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang first.